# How to set horizontally scrolled view childs width?

Tags: android-linearlayout

How do I achieve effect that on any screen there are always visible 3,5 eqally wide elements that are childs of a HorizontalScrollView?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

please find the solution as below mentiond link:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html

Comment: I know what HorizontalScrollView is and how to put child views into it but that doesn't answer my question